# loadModule gets stuck when called from webpack loader that runs in thread-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

We're trying to implement a webpack loader that, between the rest, performs the following:

1. When loading a file, look for specific dependencies.
2. Load the filtered dependencies using another loader, with a line that looks like:

```js
loaderContext.loadModule(`${filename}!=!${OTHER_LOADER_PATH}!${filename}`, (err, source) => {...})
```

(If it matters, the second loader that we use should basically return the exported content of the loaded file).
As far as we understand, the `!=!` syntax is telling to Webpack to ignore the regular loader rules that should be applied to `filename`, and instead use only the `OTHER_LOADER_PATH` to load the file. (see more details here - https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#inline-matchresource)

This works well. However, when using this method on a larger codebase, with a complex dependency graph, the compilation gets stuck.
More specifically, it gets stuck AFTER the additional loader is processing the pure dependency `filename`. It looks like it happens with dependency files that are consumed in multiple places. Meaning, if a file is a dependency to multiple files, and it gets loaded with the `OTHER_LOADER_PATH` multiple times, the build gets stuck. The `OTHER_LOADER_PATH` finishes the processing of the file, but the callback for `loaderContext.loadModule` isn't triggered.
Furthermore, This seems to happen only when using `thread-loader` (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/thread-loader). Looks like `thread-loader` is replacing the original loader context with a different, lightweight loader context. We suspect it might be causing the issue. `thread-loader` does not seem to be maintained properly anymore, and there's no other solution to properly parallelize the compilation process.

We've tried many approaches and hacks, but nothing worked properly. Our questions are:

1. Is the solution described above (using a separate loader for loading the dependencies) sound legitimate? Is there a different recommended solution?
2. How can we solve or debug the issue of `loadModule` not resolving itself?
3. Is there a replacement to `thread-loader` that still enables parallelizing the build process? Or, is there a way to use `thread-loader` so that the build won't hang?

Thank you